# How to disable logs of Exposed Framework?

Tags: gradle, kotlin-exposed

I have a kotlin desktop application with gradle builder.

I added Exposed ORM framework for my sqlite DB.

Then I noticed this framework generates a lot of logs that I don't want to see in console (I want to see only my logs generated `io.github.microutils:kotlin-logging`).

Is there any way to disable logs from Exposed using gradle properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To disable (or change logging level) you have to check your logger framework implementation documentation. Both `kotlin-logging` and `slf4j` (which used by `kotlin-logging`) just provide facades for logging.

For example, if you use `logback` you could update your configuration to show only warns and errors from an Exposed:

```
<configuration>
    // another code here
    <logger name="Exposed" level="warn" additivity="false">
       <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </logger>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Look for the file (in your project tree) "resources/logback.xml" to determine if you are using "logback".